# Conditional Probability on the Intersection Property

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know the next formula:

$P\left(A\cap B \cap C \right)=P\left( A\right) P\left( B\mid A\right) P\left(C\mid B\cap A\right)   $

How could we define the next probabilities?

a) $P\left( A\cap B\mid C\right) $

b) $P\left( A\mid B\cap C\right) $

Thank you this would help me a lot.

Comment: The definition of $P(A\mid B)$ is $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ provided that $P(B)>0$.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I experienced a confusion interval!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, just figured my own question:

$P\left( A\cap B|C\right) = \dfrac{P\left(A\cap B \cap C \right)}{P\left( C\right) }$

$P\left( A|B\cap C\right) = \dfrac{P\left(A\cap B \cap C \right)}{P\left( B\cap C\right) }$